What version of node to develop spfx
I see some questions like this from several years ago, but this question is a little different and I wonder how things are supposed to work now.
We work in a enterprise setting where we can only choose node 16.14, 18.13.0, or 20.12.1. We can choose which version of SPFx we want to install and were planning to go for 1.18.2. Which according to this documentation should work with Node v16 or v18.
However when we try and gulp serve we get an error telling us that we need need version node 18.17.1 or higher. Past versions of that page indicate when a specific version is the minimum, for example 16.13+ but the more recent releases just specify v18.
Should we just roll back to quite older versions of spfx and node or is there something I'm missing that could make it work with the options open to us?

I know you are looking for something better, but I see 2 options :( :

Roll back to SPFx 1.17 or another version that explicitly supports Node.js v16.x or v18.13.0.
Request access to Node.js 18.17.1+ if possible, to allow you to use SPFx 1.18.2.

Have you checked with SPFx 1.18 or 1.18.1? Is the behaviour the same?
